# CollectionViewSource "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Why does this code produce the error in a Windows 8 XAML application?

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

The XAML:

```
    <SemanticZoom>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView
                Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListViewStyle}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding BoardItems}" 
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ZoomedOutListViewItemContainerStyle}"
...
```

The MVVM code:

```
ObservableCollection<WritingBoardModel> boards = new ObservableCollection<WritingBoardModel>();

... // Add item models to boards.

CollectionViewSource v = new CollectionViewSource()
{
    Source = boards,
};

this.ViewModel.Add(BoardItemsViewModelKey, v);
```

If I skip the `CollectionViewSource` and directly add the `boards` instance to my view model, then it all works.

I think I need to use a `CollectionViewSource` in order to get some semantic zoom selection behaviour to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to bind to the `View` property of the CollectionViewSource like this:

```
CollectionViewSource v = new CollectionViewSource()
        {
            IsSourceGrouped = false,
            Source = boards,
        };

this.ViewModel.Add(BoardItemsViewModelKey, v.View);
```

Mind you, this doesn't help with my two `ListView`s and keeping them in selection synch in a `SemanticZoom`.

Comment: Adding `.View` to the binding if you're trying to bind to the CollectionViewSource in  a XAML binding works the same as well.

Answer (score 5):

So, `CollectionViewSource`s are weird and the way you have to bind to them is weird as well. To give you an example, in order to do it 'by the book' (the way the sample projects do), I've found it practically has to be a `StaticResource` as such:

```
<Page.Resource>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Whatev}"
                          x:Key="WhatevSource"/>
</Page.Resource>

<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WhatevSource}}"/>
```

Notice that we're not setting the source directly to the `CollectionViewSource`, but we're setting a 'pathless' `Binding`, basically using the `CollectionViewSource` as a `DataContext` (just one way to think of it, not actually technically correct).

This is the only way I've been able to get it to work, though I believe you can technically in the codebehind set the `ItemsSource` directly to the View of the `CollectionViewSource` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, doing it this way gives the same error, albeit in a blue squiggly in the XAML editor.

Comment: What error does the XAML editor say? Could you post the code that is now giving you blue squigglies, along with your Xaml CollectionViewSource declaration?

Comment: Doing it this way worked for me:
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WhatevSource}}"/>

I was binding it without mentioning Source..
<GridView ItemsSource="{StaticResource WhatevSource}"/>

Feels strange.. but it fixed that..

Answer (score 2):

In your Listview add "StaticResource" and "Source"

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WhatevSource}}"/>
```